# How to update the status automatically after 10 days using event schedular?

Tags: mysql

I have sent_date and status in my table. I wanted to update the status automatically after 10 days.

Suppose sent_date is 24/03/2018 and status is Sent/Received. So on 04/04/2018, the status should update to Aborted automatically.

I know I have to use Date_Add but for testing purpose I am making use of Date_Sub.

What I tried:

```
CREATE EVENT rot ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 day DO 
    update barter_proposals 
       set proposal_status="Aborted"
     WHERE sent_date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 day )
       AND proposal_status = "Sent/Received"
```

So here,CURDATE takes the date of the system(24/03/2018),and it is updating the 23/03/2018 status to Aborted..This works fine.

```
 CREATE EVENT rot ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 day DO 
        update barter_proposals 
           set proposal_status="Aborted"
         WHERE sent_date=DATE_SUB(sent_date, INTERVAL 1 day )
           AND proposal_status = "Sent/Received"
```

sent_date in the table can be anything. So for this, it is not working properly. What changes are required so that the status can be automatically update after 10 days?

Comment: I guess 'not working properly' means that it is not updating where send_date <= to yesterday.

Comment: i wanted to update the status after 10 days automatically...Any help will bw highly appreciated...almost wasted my 2 days on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE EVENT rot ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 day DO 
    update barter_proposals 
       set proposal_status="Aborted"
     WHERE sent_date=DATE(CURDATE()-10)
       AND proposal_status = "Sent/Received"
```